# Check id joining 3 tables

Tags: mysql

I have a MySQL JOIN query where 2 tables are joined to get the output

```
select distinct (a.error_type),a.links_id, a.crawl_cycle , b.* from $table a inner join crawler_error_type b on a.error_type = b.error_type where a.projects_id = '$pid' and b.error_priority_page_level='High'
```

Now I want to check if the value of the field `error_type` is present in the third table. If it is present then it shouldn't give me the resulted row.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add the below:

```
LEFT OUTER JOIN third_table c ON c.error_type = a.error_type
```

and

```
WHERE c.error_type is null
```

LEFT OUTER JOIN will display all the records from a table joining  on third_table. Since you do not want the record with matching error type from third_table, use `WHERE c.error_type is null`

Answer (score 0):

You need to add one more `INNER JOIN` on `third_table` as:

```
SELECT DISTINCT a.error_type, a.links_id, a.crawl_cycle , b.* 
FROM  $table a 
      INNER JOIN crawler_error_type b 
          ON a.error_type = b.error_type 
      INNER JOIN third_table c
          ON a.error_type = c.error_type 

WHERE a.projects_id = '$pid' AND 
      b.error_priority_page_level='High'.
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand it correctly, you should just be able to inner join the third table. Inner joins will on show the record if they have records in the joining tables.  If I am misunderstanding could you please elaborate.  Thx

```
select distinct (a.error_type),a.links_id, a.crawl_cycle , b.* 

from $table a 

inner join crawler_error_type b on a.error_type = b.error_type 

inner join some_table_3 c on c.error_type = a.error_type 

where a.projects_id = '$pid' and b.error_priority_page_level='High'
```